# Change source from 1.5 to 1.7 (Using the cocos command line tool)

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am trying to compile my android project using the following command line:

cocos deploy -p android -m release
But i keep getting some errors saying the following:

error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5

I tried manually modifying the individual files to fix the declaration so that it doesnt depend on 1.7, but after i did it many many errors appeared (the diamond operator one got fixed thought). So what i am thinking is that i need to make cocos compile it directly with 1.7 instead.

But i have looked for it everywhere and i can't find where to change that.

**I am not using eclipse, nor android studio, i am using the terminal directly with the cocos commands.**

Does anyone have any idea about where this is changed?

Update:

It has something to do with the java compiler, but still can't find where to change the javac settings:

```
[javac] /Users/LuisOscar/Documents/CocosProjects/Zombies/proj.android/src/net/nend/NendModule/NendIconModule.java:56: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[javac] private static HashMap<String, NendAdIconData> mNendAdIconHashMap = new HashMap<>();
[javac]                                                                                     ^
[javac]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[javac] /Users/LuisOscar/Documents/CocosProjects/Zombies/proj.android/src/net/nend/NendModule/NendModule.java:51: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[javac] private static HashMap<String, NendAdViewData> mNendAdHashMap = new HashMap<>();
[javac]                                                                                 ^
[javac] (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

Comment: Install java 1.6+ then, setup cocos paths. Make sure you have android sdk and ndk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the location, For anyone else interested this is adjusted at:

```
Android/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml
```

It's shown under compilation options:

```
<property name="java.target" value="1.7" />
<property name="java.source" value="1.7" />
```

Comment: I hit this error and this was the fix implementing MoPub v4.13 on a cocos2d-x 3.4 project.

*edit*
This also got rid of the obsolete warning:
*"[javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release"* in case anyone is looking to solve that issue too.